# Angular6 filter

Tags: filter, pipe, angular6

I'm trying to build a filter pipe in Angular 6, but it's not working properly.

.html

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchString" placeholder="Type to search..." [(ngModel)]="searchString">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<table class="table">
  <tr *ngFor="let user of users | filter2 : searchString">
    {{user.name}}
  </tr>
</table>
```

pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter2'
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if (!items) return [];
    if (!searchText) return items;
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
    return items.filter(it => {
      return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
  }
}
```

I get this error when I write inside input:

> ERROR TypeError: it.toLowerCase is not a function

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your time!

[users](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cbd067e1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchText);

Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  users:any[];
  constructor(){
    this.users = [
      {name:"John"},
      {name:"Tom"},
      {name:"Carlton"},
      {name:"Judy"},
      {name:"Ada"}
    ];
  }
}
```

Html

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchString" placeholder="Type to search..." [(ngModel)]="searchString">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<table class="table">
  <tr *ngFor="let user of users | filter2 : searchString">
    {{user.name}}
  </tr>
</table>
```

Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter2'
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if (!items) return [];
    if (!searchText) return items;
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
    return items.filter(it => {
      return it.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that. I won't get any error, but it's not working.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add pipe to your component.

Comment: And also you should use name property of item.

Comment: Sorry it was late but I've updated the response, I've tried this piece of code and it worked.